# How can I form ARIMA equation given MA and AR terms

Tags: time-series, arima, sas

[image]

Above is output from SAS.

What would be the corresponding ARIMAX equation?  I would appreciate if someone could help me write the mathematical equation, preferably in the following form:
$$
Y(t)= ay(t-1) + by(t-2) + \ldots + z
$$
where $a, b, c$ are the coefficients, and $z$ is any error term.

Comment: I think your model is definitely in trouble as your second MA polynomial has a coefficient of .97708 clearly cancelling the second of your AR coefficients .99991 . Both coefficients refer to lag 7. I will use AUTOBOX a very useful time series analysis package that I have helped develop to re-state your model in terms of the pi weights i.e. a pure autoregressive form. Poor model selection (as in this case) is due to the inopportune usage of the AIC/BIC criterion ... which is all that SAS offers as part of its inferior  "automatic process".

Comment: This looks like noon stationary process. Get the roots of characteristic polynomial first.

Comment: Reading SAS documentation should definitely help. I have never used SAS, but I cannot immagine that the documentation does not state what kind of model it is estimating. For me MA part looks suspicious since it has 2 factors, which usually is indication of SARIMA process.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of the ARIMA model (please correct me anyone if I'm wrong) is that it is equivivalent to "pre-filter" (differencing) the data $y(t)$ and set $y_{new}(t) = y(t)-y(t-1)$. Then fit an ARMA model to this new data. This would mean your ARMA model:

\begin{equation}
y_{new}(t) = (1-q^{-1}) y(t) = \frac{C}{A}e(t),
\end{equation}
where $q^{-1}$ is the difference operator $q^{-1}y(t) = y(t-1)$ and $e(t)$ is noise.

This means you get the model (in $y$) as 
\begin{equation}
(1 - q^{-1})(1+a_1q^{-1}+\ldots+a_{n_a} q^{-n_a})y(t) = (1 + c_1 q^{-1} + \ldots + c_{n_c} q^{-n_c})e(t).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Your model and coefficients expressed as a pure AR model (up to lag 12)  is here.

The equation is  multiply 1.0  time the last value and add it to

```
             1.15404 times the last value and add it to

            - .73264 times the value 2 periods ago and add it to

              .465   times the value 3 periods ago

          etc....
```

This means that the ARMAX Polynomial can be expressed as an infinite AR polynomial ... shown here to lag 12 . The coefficients are your a,b,c ...etc

```
     a,b,c
```

[image]

Comment: Your use of screenshots suggests you might appreciate knowing a better way to copy and paste material on this site: start editing the source post (preferably in another tab or window) to obtain a textbox with the original material (including $\TeX$ markup).  Copy what you want from that textbox and paste it into your reply, editing as you see fit.  Simply abandon the edits to the original once you are finished with it.

Comment: tu ...........................................